# Google Stackdriver within multiprocessing not working

Tags: python-3.x, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging

I built an API endpoint using Flask, where data is collected and combined from other APIs. In order to do this efficiently, I use multiprocess. To keep control, I want to log all steps using Google Stackdriver.

For some reason, I keep getting errors when using Google Stackdriver within my multiprocess environment. The error and later warning I get within my MWE is the following:

```
Pickling client objects is explicitly not supported.
Clients have non-trivial state that is local and unpickleable.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "C:\Users\...\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
EOFError: Ran out of input
```

Minimal Working Example (excluded Flask/API for simplicity):

```
project_name = project_name = 'budget_service'
message = 'This is a test'
labels = {
    'deployment': 'develop',
    'severity': 'info'
}

# Import libs
from google.cloud import logging
import multiprocessing as mp

# Initialize logging
logging_client = logging.Client()
logger = logging_client.logger(project_name)

# Function to write log
def writeLog(logger):
    logger.log_text(
        text = message,
        labels = labels
    )
    print('logger succeeded')

def testFunction():
    print('test')

# Run without mp
writeLog(logger)

# Run with mp
print(__name__)
if __name__ == '__main__':       
    try:
        print('mp started')

        # Initialize
        manager = mp.Manager()
        return_dict = manager.dict()
        jobs = []

        # Set up workers
        worker_log1 = mp.Process(name='testFunction', target=testFunction, args=[])
        worker_log2 = mp.Process(name='writeLog', target=writeLog, args=[logger])

        # Store in jobs
        jobs.append(worker_log1)
        jobs.append(worker_log2)


        # Start workers
        worker_log1.start()
        worker_log2.start()

        for job in jobs:
            job.join()

        print('mp succeeded')

    except Exception as err:
         print(err)
```

Why is it not possible to combine multiprocessing with Google Stackdriver? What should I adjust (what do I understand poorly) to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

As of today (04.2019), stackdriver logging still does not support multiprocessing. The solution is either to:

- Make sure your processes are started in `spawn` mode rather than `fork` (default on *nix) which prevents sharing anything
- Avoid sharing logging objects explicitly by configuring them separately in each process

Using `fork` multiprocessing is generally a bad idea with google libraries, stackdriver is not the only one causing problems.